# How to add a sprite to box2d body?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d

**I fixed. Problem solved.**

I'm new in as3 and box2D, so at least I'm learning. I have a problem to add my sprites(movieclip) to a dynamic body. The sprite appear but it give me an error and because of that all the game-prototype works bad. With the statics I don't have any problem. What can I do?

This is my code:

Before the code I set them as a variable:

```
 private var player:b2Body;
 private var mc_player:MovieClip;
```

Firstly the function of my dynamic body:

```
public function createPlayer(px:int, py:int):void
    {
        mc_player = new _pork();
        addChild(mc_player);

        var playerDef:b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
        playerDef.position.Set(px / worldScale, py / worldScale);
        playerDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;


        var playerShape:b2PolygonShape = new b2PolygonShape();
        playerShape.SetAsBox(25 / 2 / worldScale, 40 / 2 / worldScale);

        var playerForce:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
        playerForce.shape = playerShape;

        player = world.CreateBody(playerDef);
        player.CreateFixture(playerForce);
    }
```

Then a function to add the mc(movieclip):

```
private function drawPlayer():void
    {
        mc_player.x = player.GetPosition().x * worldScale;
        mc_player.y = player.GetPosition().y * worldScale;
    }
```

And in the update I just call it:

```
 private function update(e:Event):void
            {
                drawPlayer();
                }
```

The other proprieties I added, like set forces and gravity, this is not the problem.
This are the part where I think is the problem...

The error in flash:

> TypeError: Error #1009: No se puede acceder a una propiedad o a un
>   método de una referencia a un objeto nulo.    at Main/drawPlayer()    at
>   Main/update()

I don't have any idea how can I fix it

Any help, please..

Thx everyone!

**Edit:**

**Solution:**

Sorry everyone I fail in my code. The error was that I never said to the game call the player when it is in the stage(I means the in the level) and not in the menu...because of this I was calling the player before appear the player. Sorry about my mistake.. 
So is something like that to call the movieclip player:

```
private function update(e:Event):void 
{ 
//Call movieclips
 if (mc_player) {
 drawPlayer(); } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When/how is update() getting called?  Is it a matter that you've created the callback before the mc_player has been initialized?

Comment: I think what you are asking me is something like that: 

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

That is inside the function Main (the principal)

Comment: Make sure the player has been added to the stage before adding the ENTER_FRAME callback.  Similar to:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13457986/1809570

Comment: Yes I fixed it yet...I edit my question and found the solution...At least I don't have any more problems..By the way thank you :)

Comment: Excellent! Glad it worked out - I know how frustrating these things are.