# actionscript 3.0 TypeError

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, timeline, typeerror

Im getting this annoying error and I can`t figure out what the problem might be...

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at simplifyVirSys_fla::copyRightAthenaAcademy_1/initiateApp()`

My main time line has two frames:
frame1-the intro and frame2-the application itself

The intro is a movieclip. The code on the last frame of the intro mc goes like this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initiateApp);

function initiateApp(e:Event){
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

So after playing the intro, it should jump to frame 2 of the main time line. And that`s where the output window goes crazy with the #1009 error.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the player is loaded and ready to go before adding the EnterFrame eventListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, this.ready);

function ready(e:Event) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, ready);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initiateApp);
}

function initiateApp(e:Event){ 
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answers guys - but I figured out it yesterday reading a similar thread - user named Vivo answered it and I just applied it to my problem. My code goes like this now (and it works):                                                                 stop();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initiateApp);
    function initiateApp(e:Event){
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initiateApp);
    }

Comment: While this works, it's not bullet proof.  The code I posted above guarantees that the player is loaded, the stage and movieclips are available and the app will always run.  You might want to check to see how your code does if you simulate slow connection speeds.  Also, if you ever load a external swf, the same code works for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try validating the root.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, initiateApp);

function initiateApp(e:Event){
    if (root)
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

I don't understand why you are trying to go to the frame 2 using an EnterFrame Event. You simply must put a `stage.gotoAndStop(2)` or `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2)` in the last frame of you animation.

Comment: thanks for the advice. although my problem is already solved, I`ll check out also your solution. And to answer your question - I`am / was trying to go to the frame 2 using an EnterFrame Event, because I am an Actionscript3 beginner, or an AS3 noob, one might say...

Comment: Just tried it out. The stage.gotoAndStop(2) doesn`t work for me, the MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2) works fine.