# How to put constant 3d rotation of a movieclip into a loop on the Y axis in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, syntax, 3d

First of all the idea is to get a circle rotating

The following is from a tutorial and it works but brings up a string of errors. How would I go about putting the code inside the lightbeam function into a functional loop instead of the current syntax.

```
//Sets variable angle and speed
/*var angle3:Number = 0;*/
var speed3:Number = 5;
var angle3:Number = 0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, lightbeam);
//Function to let the glowing orb rotate in 3d 360 degrees.;
function lightbeam(e:Event)
{



    angle3 < 360 ? angle3 +=  speed3: angle3 = 0;
    glow_mc.rotationY = angle3;



}
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: The question is , do you know how to decipher the code of the first line inside the function it's from a tutorial and it works except I want to make it simpler and put it into some sort of loop so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's a flash ternary operator

```
angle3 < 360 ? angle3 +=  speed3: angle3 = 0;
```

is the same as

```
if(angle3 < 360) {
   angle3 +=  speed3;
} else {
   angle3 = 0;
}
```

Comment: The enterframe event should update this every frame and autorotate - what errors are you seeing?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at RECOVER_welcome_fla::MainTimeline/lightbeam()                                                       Got this error repeating over and over

Comment: Have you done this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457037/actionscript-3-0-typeerror/13457986#13457986

Comment: The code you have entered above gets rid of the errors but unfortunately the rotation of the lightbeam no longer happens

Comment: I haven't done that yet. I'm attempting it now, my partner in the group is the coder but I'll see if i can figure it out. Thanks

Comment: did you add the last line as well?  glow_mc.rotationY = angle3;

Comment: also, Flash uses Radians, so if your tutorial is using a framework that automatically converts, then you're ok.  If not, you might want to trace the values and see what's happening.  Also, rotationZ will rotate the object on the screen in 2D clockwise for positive values.